# Zend Form add span to dd

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form, zend-form-element

I am trying to make custom decorators and I came to an issue.
Below is my code:

```
$oElement->setDecorators(array(
    'ViewHelper',
    array(array( 'data' => 'HtmlTag'),
    array('tag' => 'dd', 'span' => 'myspan', 'class' => $class . ' myclass ' )),
    array('Label', array('tag' => 'dt', 'class' => $class))
));
```

I want to add a span inside the dd so that after rendering the form it looks like:

```
<dd class="myclass"> <span> </span> </dd>
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't test this as don't have Zend installed on my tablet, but think you have to add the span:

```
$oElement->setDecorators(array(
    'ViewHelper',
    array(array('data' => 'HtmlTag'), 
        array('tag' => 'span', 'class' => $class . 'myspan')),
    array(array('span'   => 'HtmlTag'), 
        array('tag' => 'dd', 'class' => $class . 'myclass')),
    array('Label', array('tag' => 'dt', 'class' => $class))
));
```

I remember getting fed up with Zend decorators personally and Zend Forms in general as it felt like it took more effort than just making forms in HTML. Hope this helps anyway.

Comment: This is producing the dd wrapped inside the span "<span><dd></dd></span". i need it the other way => "<dd><span></span></dd>"

Comment: I switched the dd and spans from your answer Oshawott and it worked. Is it confirm ?!

Comment: That sounds right, yes. I didn't get to test it, my tablet has no PHP running on it. Glad it helped though, will edit for future readers.

Comment: @user2134817 - What did you mean by 'is it confirm?' -- sorry am not a native English speaker. :)